# babel & karma & webpack not working

Tags: karma-runner, webpack, babeljs

I'm using babel with webpack, and test with karma and jasmine. 
In order to use `Set()` (requires a polyfill), I've added :

`loader: 'babel-loader?optional[]=runtime'`

to the configuration.

This work's perfectly for the application itself, but the tests are not working, throwing:

`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '_core.Object')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved it myself:

1. remove `?optional[]=runtime'`
2. add to config :

`

```
files: [
            'node_modules/babel-core/browser-polyfill.js',
      ... (rest of the needed files) 
    ],
```